# Difference between ":eq()" and .eq()

Tags: jquery

I have recently started learning jQuery. Considering follwing html structure, I want to know, what is basic difference between selectors `$('ul>li:eq(2)')` and `$('ul>li').eq(2)`.

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They do the same thing, but one is significantly slower: http://jsperf.com/eq-vs-eq

`:eq()` is not a CSS pseudo-selector, which makes the first selector a jQuery selector. Therefore, it has to be parsed by the Sizzle selector library, which is written in JavaScript.

The second one is a regular CSS selector and will be passed directly into `document.querySelectorAll`, which is implemented natively and will end up running much faster.

Answer (score 1):

There's essentially no difference between them, except in performance. jQuery has many methods that are equivalent to selectors.