# jQuery selectors confusing

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd appreciate if someone also points me to theory sources so i can grasp it better.

Suppose i have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

and this JavaScript code:

```
alert($("ul li:eq(0)").length);

alert($("ul").find("li:eq(0)").length);

alert($("ul").find("li").eq(0).length);
```

I get 1,2,1 as output. I can understand why I got 1 in the last case but why is the 1 and 2nd line of JavaScript code giving me different outputs.

fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/ishansoni22/pntz6kfx/

Comment: when in doubt, just use `.eq(0)` any way - it's much faster anyway because it permits the use of `document.querySelectorAll()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eq` is a strange jQuery selector, not really consistent with the CSS based logic of most selectors (emphasis mine in this [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) extract):

> The index-related selectors (:eq(), :lt(), :gt(), :even, :odd) filter the set of elements that have matched **the expressions that precede them**

In short, the `eq(0)` in the first case applies to the **whole** `ul li`.

`$("anything :eq(0)")` can return at most one element.

While in the second case, the `"li:eq(0)"` selector is applied by `find` to all matches of `$("ul")`.

Comment: Thanks. Is :last also an index related selector.(can't really find out from the documentation), since it also behaves in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

`alert($("ul li:eq(0)").length);` => length of first li within ul, `:eq(0)` always returns 1 or 0 elements.

`alert($("ul").find("li:eq(0)").length);` => Number of times an li exits within ul

`alert($("ul").find("li").eq(0).length);` => length of number of times `li` exits within `ul`

Comment: What do you mean by "length" in "Length of the first li" and "This is just the length of the above statement"?

Comment: @DavidHedlund First statement is edited. And the last statement means length of number of times `li` exits within `ul`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. What is the difference between "number of times ..." and "length of number of times ..."?

Comment: If there is 1 `li` within `ul` then 1 is the value. Also the length of 1 is 1. I hope that clarified it.

Comment: I was just unclear about the "the length of 1 is 1" bit. I don't really know what you want to say by that. Regardless, your second statement seems off. "Number of times an li exist within ul". Did you miss that there is an `:eq(0)` selector in that code as well? It doesn't simply count all list items within unordered lists.

Comment: What I meant was `eq(0)` returns 1 & then the length of that is 1.

Comment: `eq(0)` returns a jQuery collection of *zero or one elements*, not the number `1`. `eq(0).length` returns the length of that collection, i.e. the number `0` or `1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113135/discussion-between-ani-menon-and-david-hedlund).

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the following link to get a better handle of :eq & .eq() 
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/eq-vs-eq

If you still have doubts, here is a possible duplicate of this question:
[Difference between ":eq()" and .eq()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592427/difference-between-eq-and-eq)